# Can anyone identify this plant?

Tags: identification

Can anyone identify [this plant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/044EK.jpg) that I found growing in my backyard?

It has a thin stem, long thin leaves that are paired on the stem, with a prominent central rib on the leaves.

*Click on image for full size*

[image]

Comment: Knowing where you live would help in identification.  Are those three spiky ball-shaped objects part of the same plant?

Comment: I'm in Santa Clara, California. And yes, they're part of the same plant.

Comment: Some variety of Lychee (litchi) maybe?

Comment: These plants grow wild and weedy here in South Africa. Despite looking quite intimidating, the spikes on the balls are soft.

Answer (score 12):

It is balloon plant aka...um...'hairy balls' (*Gomphocarpus physocarpus* aka [*Asclepias physocarpa*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asclepias_physocarpa)), a milkweed native to southeastern Africa.